# Should I use Interlocked.Exchange here or is a standard write sufficient?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, interlocked

The following method attempts to obtain a lock which is shared with some other thread. In the event that the lock can be obtained within a time period, some Action will be executed.

If the lock cannot be obtained within the specified time period, I want to try the whole process again on a separate thread by spawning a Task. I don't want my initial thread hanging around waiting to obtain a lock because performance is important in this scenario. However I do not want any more tasks to be created until this task completes. In other words there should never be more than a single task running at any given time. Any subsequent calls to 'ExecuteOrOffload' that are made while a Task is still running must not be allowed to create another Task.

I came up with the following solution and I would like to know if my setter method (setFlag) should use Interlocked.Exchange to change the flags value, or whether it makes any difference at all? The code runs on a machine with a large number of cores.

```
    void Main()
    {
        //I currently use this
        ExecuteOrOffload(_theLock, () => { }, () => _theFlag, newVal => _theFlag = newVal, 0);

        //Should I use this instead? i.e. - Does my setter need to use Interlocked.Exchange? 
        ExecuteOrOffload(_theLock, () => { }, () => _theFlag, newVal => Interlocked.Exchange(ref _theFlag, newVal));
    }

    private object _theLock = new Object();
    private int _theFlag = 0;


    //Flag = 0. Allow a new Task to start if needed
    //Flag = 1. A Task is already running. Don't allow new tasks to be created
    private void ExecuteOrOffload(object thelock, Action theAction, Func<int> getFlag, Action<int> setFlag, int timeout = 0)
    {
       bool acquiredLock = false;

       try
       {
        //If the lock can be obtained, execute the Action
        Monitor.TryEnter(thelock, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout), ref acquiredLock);
        if (acquiredLock)
        {
            theAction();
        }
        //The lock was not obtained. Either offload to a new task or do nothing
        else
        {
            //Get the current value of the flag
            var currentValue = getFlag();
            //Try set the flag to 1. Only one thread should manage to do this.
            var originalValue = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref currentValue, 1, 0); 

            //If this thread didn't change the flag then just return.
            if (originalValue == currentValue)
            {
                return;
            }

            //The thread that gets here changes the actual flag value
            setFlag(1);
            //...and starts a new task
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    //Retry the whole process from a Task. This time the flag is set to 1 and a new Task will not be created should the lock time out
                    ExecuteOrOffload(thelock, theAction, getFlag, setFlag, 2);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Task completed (either timed out or executed the action, we don't care which). Reset the flag to allow future calls to start a new Task
                    setFlag(0);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Log exception
    }
    finally
    {
        //If this thread took the lock, release it
        if (acquiredLock)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(thelock);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That get/setFlag pattern is completely racy. This is not safe. You're not doing *any* synchronization on the shared variable.

The `Interlocked.CompareExchange` you're doing is on an unshared local variable. That never helps. A smart JIT, which we don't have, would just optimize this interlocked operation out (or convert it to a fence).

Perform the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` on a shared variable. In that case there is no separate store and your question is resolved.

Comment: Do you mean I should remove the 'currentValue = getFlag()' and replace it with just '_theFlag'? There is a reason I used the getter/setter rather than accessing the _theFlag directly (which would have been simpler). The class in question has two flags, used for separate purposes. So I need to know which of the two flags to use depending on who called the method. This leaves two options - I can pass the correct flag into the method (by reference, hence the getter/setter) or I can duplicate the method entirely and have each method use the correct flag.

Comment: You could pass the right flag using `ref myFlag`. Or, use a wrapper class around the flag. The wrapper would expose a field.

Comment: I've tried both of those solutions, but you can't pass by reference into a Task. Also, with the wrapper (like a flag object with an int property) still won't let you change the value without copying locally). I'm struggling to come up with a way to do that. I'd ideally not have to copy/paste the entire method and just access the correct flag in each. There must be a way to do this.

Comment: You can ref-reference a field. class c { int field; }. ref new c().field.

Comment: Thats brilliant - solves my problem exactly. Thanks for your help. I learned quite a lot from that.